# What advantages does Mvc jquery validation offer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

What advantages, if any, does MVC jQuery Validation offer over the built-in MVC client validation?

I've used the built-in validation and am just curious as to if I'm missing anything or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about customisation?  I'm sure not everything is covered with the standard validators.

For example, our products are meant for people over 14yo so it's be nice to validate that client side rather than tie the server up with silly requests.

You can then share this and have a standard way of validating DOB.

Answer (score 0):

MVC jQuery validation is done on the front end (client side), without submitting data to the controller (Server side). So it can save you some bandwidth/processing.

If you have a slow or overloaded server, users will get a quicker response to validation errors this way as well.

Server side validation is essential/required since it makes sure you are getting good data before you save it. The client side is nice to have, but shouldn't be all you have since its possible to bypass.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't make my question clear.  I meant are there any advantages to using mvc jquery validation over the built-in mvc validation using client validation (ie. Html.EnableClientValidation())